# Add leading and trailing gap UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

[image: prototype cell]

So I want to add space to the left and right of the cell, so that the cell doesn't fill up the entire width of the screen.

How would I go about that?

Comment: take a uiveiw inside of cell containview and set leading and trailing = 10 and top and bottom = 0.

Comment: @Jaydip Already considered, but that doesn't move the disclosure indicator

Comment: share code plaese

Comment: Use Tableview on UIviewController and leave the space to tableview. by which Disclosure indicator will also move.

Answer (score 1):

add this code in your cell's class

```
 override func layoutSubviews() {
    // Set the width of the cell
    self.bounds = CGRect(x: self.bounds.origin.x, y: self.bounds.origin.y, width: self.bounds.size.width - 40, height: self.bounds.size.height)
    super.layoutSubviews()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Set x coordinate of tableview = Spacing you want for the cell from
- the left Set width of tableview = screenwidth - Spacing you want for 
  the cell from the left
- Then add leading and trailing constraint to the tableview

## Example

[image]